# custom log format in bash logger

Tags: linux, bash, shell, logging, systemctl

I have default log format like this:

```
+ logger --stderr '[START]'
<13>Jun 29 13:10:02 ada: [START]
```

but I need something like this:

```
+ logger --stderr '[START]'
2018-06-29 11:11:43,524 1 INFO ada: [START]
```

I already consulted `man logger` but no illumination on how to do custom timestamps. I hope there is something like:

```
+ export LOGGER_FORMAT="{year}-{date}-{month} ... {level} {user}: {message}"
+ logger --stderr '[START]'
2018-06-29 11:11:43,524 1 INFO ada: [START]
```

Is there something like this?

journalctl already is doing it well, and it receive messages from `logger` command. How does that work?

```
journalctl

-- Logs begin at Tue 2015-02-03 21:48:52 UTC, end at Tue 2015-02-03 22:29:38 UTC. --
Feb 03 21:48:52 localhost.localdomain systemd-journal[243]: Runtime journal is u
```

Answer (score 1):

`logger` generates [syslog messages](https://www.networkmanagementsoftware.com/what-is-syslog/) which have a standard format. There's a proscribed format for the timestamp in order for syslog tools to be able to parse it. It can't be and shouldn't be changed.

The systemd journal interprets the syslog messages as they're generated, parsing and storing each of the parts in its internal database in a custom format. You can do the same thing if you want to print the log messages in a different way: read up on how syslog messages are formatted, write a script or regex to pull out the component pieces, and then print them out however you like.